# Primefaces dialog component hide behind the browser screen

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am developing a project with `Primefaces 5.1` and `JSF 2.2`.

In my project, I used `dialog` component to show some details to the user's.

When I drag the `dialog` into the top of the browser screen when browser scroll is down, its getting hide behind the browser screen after that can not close the `dialog` box.

Here, I added a sample code.

Please, help me to control the behind screen hiding.

**Sample Code:**

```
<h:body>
    <h:form>
       <p:panel header="Test" style="height:1500px;">
         <p:commandButton value="Click" oncomplete="PF('dialogBoxId').show();"/>
       </p:panel>
    </h:form>
   <p:dialog header="Alert" id="dialogBoxId" widgetVar="dialogBoxId"/>
</h:body>
```

Comment: Seems like a CSS issue. What about setting it to `draggable="false"`?

Comment: @ Xtreme Biker , If we use the draggable="false" the we can't drag the dialog box on the screen. What I need is to control this hiding(dialog) with dragging the dialog box. Externally, I don't use any other CSS.

Comment: You lack some info in your question: is it happening in a concrete browser or every of them? This is not reproducible with the dialogs in the PF showcase (at least not with PF 6.1): https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/dialog/basic.xhtml You might want to add an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) with your concrete case.

Comment: Yes,always try a newer version first

Comment: @kukeltjie I try latest version but  face same issue

Comment: Like @XtremeBiker wrote, showcase does not exhibit this problem. Please create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem

Comment: @Kukeltje and Xtreme Biker, I have updated my question with sample code.